# Using Bootcamp with Windows Recovery Disks?

Tags: macos, windows-vista, installation, operating-systems, multi-boot

My friend is a regrettable Mac owner and wants to play some Windows-only games. I recently built a new computer with 7 and kept the CD Key from my old Vista 32-bit installation. He has a 1-2 year old Mac laptop (don't know specific model, should be a newish version of the OS and 64-bit).

I thought it would be as easy as getting the .iso from Microsoft and applying the key but apparently it's not exactly set up that way. There is no official .iso download, and even if there was, some people seem to be saying that my manufacturer key wouldn't work anyway? (I.E. the old computer came with Vista 32-bit pre-installed from the store).

I have my original vista recovery disks (2007!) but will this work with Bootcamp? Is there a way around this? It seems like the recovery disks will put a lot of the old "shipware" back on like Norton 2007, etc. I also don't want it to eat my friend's OS X install by mistake.

Anyone have some experience with this?

Comment: You won't be able to give your friend your license.

Comment: What Ramhound means is, OEM licenses cannot be transferred to a different machine, only ownership of the machine as a whole can be transferred. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en-gb/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx#faq3) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssmallbiz/archive/2009/10/27/no-oem-microsoft-windows-licenses-cannot-be-transferred-to-another-pc.aspx) for more.

Comment: That's incredibly disappointing but thanks for letting me know. Glad I asked before trying it.